# Extract only numbers started with "/" and ended with "-" using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have url address in one of my variable:

```
$a = "http://www.example.com/cat1/something/subcat/543210-1abce-dsef100-199-test.html"
```

I want to select from this string only numbers "543210", and to select these numbers I know that these numbers start after sign `/` and they end before sign `-`. I tried to modify this code:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $a);
```

But I don't know where I should add `/` and `-` to make this code works properly.

*P.S. I know I can do this with php function `explode` by `/` and find correct piece, but url address can contains different numbers of `/`, so I should use regex.*

Comment: Just explode and extract the number from the last token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookaheads:

```
(?<=/)(\d+)(?=-)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cH8gH0/2)

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match( '~(?<=/)(\d+)(?=-)~', $input, $m))
   echo $m[1]; //=> 543210
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. it uses lookahead and lookbehind method to extract digits

```
(?<=\/)\d{0,}(?=-)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tS4iI2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
\/([0-9]+)\-
```